# a simple tensorflow test from book

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I copy a simple tensorflow test from the book written by Sam Abrahams. In chapter 4,when I test the softmax.py about the iris.data,the program has no errors but does not have any results. I debug the program for several days but don't know how to debug it.The code is as follows. This problem puzzles me almost one week and thanks to anyone answers this question. Thank you very much!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4, 3]), name="weights")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]), name="bias")

def combine_inputs(X):
    return tf.matmul(X, W) + b

def inference(X):
    return tf.nn.softmax(combine_inputs(X))

def loss(X, Y):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=combine_inputs(X), labels=Y))

def read_csv(batch_size, file_name, record_defaults):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/" + file_name])
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    decoded = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
    return tf.train.shuffle_batch(decoded,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  capacity=batch_size * 50,
                                  min_after_dequeue=batch_size)
def inputs():
    sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width, label =\
        read_csv(100, "iris.data", [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [""]])
    label_number = tf.to_int32(tf.argmax(tf.to_int32(tf.stack([
        tf.equal(label, ["Iris-setosa"]),
        tf.equal(label, ["Iris-versicolor"]),
        tf.equal(label, ["Iris-virginica"])
    ])), 0))
    features = tf.transpose(tf.stack([sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width]))
    return features, label_number

def train(total_loss):
    learning_rate = 0.01
    return tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(total_loss)

def evaluate(sess, X, Y):
    predicted = tf.cast(tf.argmax(inference(X), 1), tf.int32)
    print (sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(predicted, Y), tf.float32))))

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    X, Y = inputs()
    total_loss = loss(X, Y)
    train_op = train(total_loss)
    training_steps = 1000
    for step in range(training_steps):
        sess.run([train_op])
    evaluate(sess, X, Y)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

Comment: I change some apis because some apis can't use in tensorflow 1.5.

Comment: What do you mean by the program does not "have any results?"

Comment: @AkshayAgrawal it means the program don't show any error and warning.it stops when steps into "sess.run([train_op])" and can't go on.